# How to find string from txt file and store in variable in BASH

Tags: bash, shell, grep

Requirement is to find a string from txt file and store it to variable.

file look like this(rsa.txt)

```
Encrypting String
... Input string        : Test_123
... Encrypted string    : $ENC(JEVOQyhZbVpkQmM0L3ArT2c4M05TZks5TmxRPT1+KQ==)
```

Required output (variable name : encstring):

`encstring = $ENC(JEVOQyhZbVpkQmM0L3ArT2c4M05TZks5TmxRPT1+KQ==)`

I tried below code but showing no result

`encstring=$(grep -oE '$ENC[^()]*==)' <<< rsa.txt)`

Comment: You are searching for an occurance of `$ENC` which is **not** followed by an open or closed parenthesis. However, in your input file, there is an open parenthese after `$ENC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
encstring=$(sed -n 's/.*\(\$ENC(.*)\).*/\1/p' rsa.txt)
# OR
encstring=$(grep -oP '\$ENC\(.*?\)' rsa.txt)
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/XHvGCL):

```sh
s='Encrypting String
... Input string        : Test_123
... Encrypted string    : $ENC(JEVOQyhZbVpkQmM0L3ArT2c4M05TZks5TmxRPT1+KQ==)'
encstring=$(sed -n 's/.*\(\$ENC(.*)\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s")
echo "$encstring"
# => $ENC(JEVOQyhZbVpkQmM0L3ArT2c4M05TZks5TmxRPT1+KQ==)
```

The `sed -n 's/.*\(\$ENC(.*)\).*/\1/p'` command does the following:

- `-n`  suppresses the default line output
- `s/.*\(\$ENC(.*)\).*/\1/` - finds any text, then captures `$ENC(...)` into Group 1 and then matches the rest of the string, and replaces the match with the Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution.

The `grep -oP '\$ENC\(.*?\)'` command extracts all `$ENC(...)` matches, with any chars, as few as possible, between `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 4):

With `awk`, could you please try following. Simply, search for string `/Encrypted string` along with a condition to check if last field of that line has `$ENC` in it then last field for that line by using `$NF`.

```
encstring=$(awk '/Encrypted string/ && $NF~/\$ENC/{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for `ENC` which is followed by 0 or more occurances of something which is **not** an open or closed parenthesis. However, in your input file, there **is** an open parenthese after `ENC`. Therefore `[^()]*` matches the null string. After this you expect the string `==`)`. This would match only for the input` ENC==)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `$` as `\$` as it means "end of string" with `-E`